# Nonparametric or robust alternative to factorial repeated measures design

Tags: repeated-measures, categorical-data, nonparametric, proportion, robust

**I have a repeated measures design with two factors** (two levels each). Each subject has a number of trials with each of the four combinations of the two factors. Though some combinations weren't carried out on a few of the subjects. **The response variable is proportion data** with lots of zeros, meaning a general linear mixed model/repeated measures anova is not appropriate (as residuals are non-normal).

I have tried a generalised linear mixed model, using the *lmer* function in R (*lme4* package), with my two factors as fixed variables and subject as a random variable, but the residuals are not particularly normal. This is true using a poisson error distribution with a log link or using a binomial error distribution with a logit or probit link (though the latter is best).

**I was wondering if I could use a robust or non-parametric test in R to look at the effects of my factors on the reponse variable (taking into account the repeated measures)?** I came across Brunner's *nparLD* package, but it doen't work for my data because a) *each* subject experiences *each* combination of factors, and b) there is no time variable.